# Lots of platforms, same core codebase, best strategy?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, api, codeigniter

I am developing a small web app.  There isn't any advanced functionality, just basic queries from a database.

The website itself allows log ins via usual means and Facebook Connect, it then has some CRUD functionality.

I will be creating a 'native' Facebook app for it, aswell as an iPhone application and an Android application.

My question is, what's the best way to maintain the codebase?

I have done this before where I created a basic API that allowed me to add, edit and delete database records, and I then used HTTP POSTs to the API across all platforms.  This made it extremely easy to maintain the codebase, fix bugs, make updates, etc, as I only had to update one place.  The individual apps themselves only really had some skinning and then some cURL requests.  Although this worked great for the mobile apps (iPhone and Android), it did make unnecessary http requests on the website and Facebook app.

What is the best way to approach this situation?  Should I create 2 websites (Facebook and normal website) and an API?  This would make it more difficult to maintain, but much more stable and faster.  Just an API, which would make it easy to maintain?

The codebase is PHP in CodeIgniter with MySQL as the database.

Comment: I fully do not understand what are You asking. You said that You did the same (or simillar) web before and that it was very simple to maintain it, so why asking again? Why don't You use the same approach again???

Comment: I mentioned that it was easy to maintain, but it created lots of unnecessary http requests.  As anyone would tell you, this is a very backwards way of passing data around when you're querying the same machine.  It's like posting a letter to your next door neighbour instead of delivering it yourself.

Comment: I just now build a website with simple API (something simillar to XML-RPC) and an android app. Website has its own frontend and backend (administration), API stands next to it only for communicational purposes (to communicate with android and iphone apps). And I do not see nothing bad on this approach... Only one con - when the database is changed (for some reason), I have to update frontend+backend PHP part operating above it, API and android app as well. But You won't keep from half of it anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should create an API with php classes, and then have a HTTP API wrapped around it.

**PHP class API:**

```
<?php // myproducts.class.php

class MyProducts
{
  static function addProduct($name, $price)
  {
    // add the product
  }
}
```

**And then your HTTP API:**

```
<?php // api/products.php

// read HTTP POST and decode it as json
$postParams = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if (!$postParams)
  throw new exception("Could not decode POST data, invalid JSON.");

// run the desired action
$classMethod = $postParams['action'];
$arguments = $postParams['arguments'];
$result = call_user_func_array(array('MyProducts', $classMethod), $arguments);

// print result as JSON
print json_encode($result);
```

With this, you can easily write an obj-c class to talk to the HTTP API. It might look something like:

```
NSData *postData = [@"{\"action\": \"addProduct\", \"arguments\": [\"Foo\", 42.00]}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:API_URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

NSLog(@"response: %@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
```

Obviously you'll want to find an Obj-C API for encoding/decoding JSON. I am using [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON)

Answer (score 1):

We have been using Kohana since January.  We moved from Codeigniter, and it is quite lovely.  The cascading file system makes it easy to organize your code.

An example of multi-platform use is Android.  We've pushed a majority of the logic into php, then we pull that into an Android WebView, with some helpers for connectivity and speed, and it displays like a native app.

With Kohana, just create a JSON view for API calls.  You can check the request to see if it is AJAX to decide whether to use a JSON or other view.

To decide between browser or mobile app, we set a user agent string unique to our mobile app, then test for it php-side.  Also, we have a view hierarchy that lets us have a few different layout files.  There is one for mobile requests, one for the web application, one for a certain type of user, etc.

Overall, Kohana is more flexible than Codeigniter, and a great base to build a web application and API on.

The downside to Kohana is that the documentation is rather poor.  However, once you start using it, you will understand it quickly.  The codebase is clean and easy to read through.

Sorry if I went on about Kohana to much, but, if you want to use php and have the flexibility you seem to crave, this is the place to start, IMHO.

Comment: He already mentioned he's using CI- I would recommend against jumping ship willy nilly, though I did move from CI to Kohana for the flexibility reasons. Kohana's documentation has greatly improved over the past couple months, and that is less and less of a well-founded criticism against Kohana.

Answer (score 1):

I would take an N-Tier approach. Treat the "mobile" (iOS and Facebook) apps as the highest level tier. They spend most of their time displaying data and getting input from the user. Through a healthy dose of AJAX, they work with the PHP app, who serves as the "Controller" handling business logic and dealing with persistence & concurrency. Yes, there is a lot of data flying around, but don't optimize prematurely. As you develop your app, think of where you can cache data, and as you find excessive requests, optimize in later versions. Unfortunately, there is really no entity-relation manager that crosses the Javascript/PHP boundary, so it's roll-you-own for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a few projects like the one you describe. Same platform, codeigniter and MySQL, which makes little difference in this case. 
One thing I've found useful so far is that when your website is viewed from the facebook iframe, the user agent hitting your site is

```
'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
```

so you can detect it.

Sometimes you can get away with just changing the css file based on the user agent, if you don't need authentication. If you need authentication, just write a separate controller for it, or use the js SDK. If this is not enough, or your site is more complex, have separate views for facebook and the normal website, and switch them according to the user agent. 
Can't help you with the API, but I imagine you will use the same models for the API as for the website, separate controller is a must.

Comment: So you'd suggest the same codebase for everything, with different controllers for the API, and a different template for Facebook?  Makes sense I guess, might have to look at better separation of files within CodeIgniter.  I know you can split the folders into: /login/controllers|models|views/ instead of /controllers|models|views/login/, which may be useful

Comment: Well, in a nutshell yes. I've been doing only facebook programming for the past year, so my mind immediately went there. What usually happens to me is I end up with a large model file, and disposable, short as possible controllers and views. Also if you plan to maintain this for longer then a year, separate the facebook parts as much as possible, because they change often. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

With a little forethought you can get an API for very little extra effort, particularly if both it and your website are built around REST principles. For example, if you have an "add" method in a controller, this will do almost exactly the same thing for both the website and the API. If you set up a data tree (with arrays or objects) to pass to the view, you can just return the JSON-encoded representation of this tree if the request is being made through the API.

As for the Facebook application, depending how much it has in common with the main website you could build both sites on the same codeigniter install with some routing and / or URL rewriting magic, letting you share any common models, controllers, or similar views if you are using an extensible templating library.